# Collecting features from multiple layers, with different attribute fields, in one layer using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, fields-attributes

I am developing a plugin for Qgis. I have **three layers** that **contain polygon geometries**, and that need to be **combined in one layer**. During this process, I also **collect all the attributes from the input features** and **write them into the output layer**. However, the **input layers have different attribute sets**. The code, which I have written **sets attributes to a feature based on the position** of attributes, which **vary for different input layers**. So the question is:

***How can I set the attributes to a QgsFeature in the output layer based on the name of the field that this attribute had in the input layer?***

Here is the code that does the job now, but mixes the attribute values in the output layer:

```
# 1) Create a temporary output layer
output_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=epsg:4326", "Combined polygons", "memory")

# 2) Create a list of layers. Layers are retrieved from the plugin dialog earlier in
#the code. There are more than two layers. Here, for simplicity, working with 
#only two of them
input_layers= [(input1,"Polygons_before"),(input2, "Polygons_after")]
output_layer_provider = output_layer.dataProvider()

new_field_inserted=False # This will be used later for inserting a new field

# 3)Iterate through the input layers to combine them in one layer
for layer, name in input_layers:
     collected_features = []

     #Get the input layer attribute fields
     layer_attr = layer.dataProvider().fields().toList()

     #Add a new field for distinguishing features from different input
     # layers in the output layer. 
     if new_field_inserted==False:
        new_field = QgsField("mask_type", QVariant.String, "text", 50)
        layer_attr.insert(1, new_field)
        new_field_inserted = True # Set this variable to True to avoid inserting the field miltiple times.

     #Add input attribute fields to output layer
     output_layer_provider.addAttributes(layer_attr)
     output_layer.updateFields()

     #Get the input features
     features = layer.getFeatures()

     #Collect input features in a list
     for feat in features:
         geom = feat.geometry()
         attr = feat.attributes()
         attr.insert(1,name)
         feature = QgsFeature()
         feature.setGeometry(geom)
         feature.setAttributes(attr)
         collected_features.append(feature)

      #Add collected features to the output layer
      output_layer_provider.addFeatures(collected_features)

 QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(output_layer)
```

Comment: I understand that those layers don't have any relationship key, right?

Comment: No, they don't.

Comment: Is there any reason for not to use this qgis algorithm `native: mergevectorlayers`?

Comment: Yes, the reason is that a new field shoud be added to attribute table in the output file. This field will be filled with a specific name for features from different layer so that the input features can be distinguished from each other in the input layer. I modfifed the code to show this.

Comment: `mergevectorlayers` add a new field, identified the source layer and another with the path to the layer

Comment: Are you asking for the QGIS equivalent to what is called [Field Mapping](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/python/mapping-fields.htm) in ArcGIS? For example take two fields with different names in different layers and combine to one field in the output of merge?

Comment: @FranRaga, I tried the mergevectorlayers algorithm. It seems to be a nice solution for this problem. However, I got another problem: 
Before merging, I use qgis:polygonize to polygonize some of my polyline layers. I then use native:fixgeometries to fix some invalid geometries. So finally when I merge the resulting layers from previous algorithms, the layer field in merged layer gets filled with only one value- "output".  This seems to be related to names that processing algorithms assign to their resulting layer. Altough layer variable that I assign is different. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: @BERA, yes, field mapping is the solution I am looking for. Do you know an alternative in pyqgis?

Comment: @FranRaga, Another problem with mergevetorlayers is that some vector layers contain a field with the same name as in other layers, but diffferent type (double and integer). The algorithm throughs a Critical error: 2019-04-26T15:49:02     CRITICAL    PLATEID2 field in layer output has different data type than in other layers (double instead of integer). 
Do you know how to overcome this? Note that in the error 'output' is the name of one of the layers being merged.